# How to define array query parameter in Open 3.0.3?

Tags: scala, rest, sbt, openapi, openapi-generator

I am using openapi 3.0.3 with sbt. I need to add an optional array query parameter in on endpoint. GroupBy parameter is not necessary, there could be minimum 0 or max 2 values. Here's what I have done -

```
parameters:
        - name: groupBy
          in: query
          description: Group by
          required: false
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              type: string
```

When I use `sbt openApiGenerate` the following method signature is generated -

```
def getStats(repoHrn: String, groupBy: String)
      (implicit toEntityMarshallerBadRequestDetails: ToEntityMarshaller[BadRequestDetails], toEntityMarshallerIdStat: ToEntityMarshaller[IdStat]): Route
```

I need it to be generated as -

```
def getStats(repoHrn: String, groupBy: Option[Array[String]])
      (implicit toEntityMarshallerBadRequestDetails: ToEntityMarshaller[BadRequestDetails], toEntityMarshallerIdStat: ToEntityMarshaller[IdStat]): Route
```

I tried several things, nothing seems to work.
I read the doc but I don't know what is something I am missing here.

Comment: Your parameter definition is correct. You might want to add `maxItems: 2` alongside `type: array`, but it's optional. The issue looks like a bug in the code generator.